# NPM outdated throws npm ERR! Not implemented yet

Tags: npm

Since I updated to npm 6.9.0 (node 8.12.0) I'm getting this error when running `npm outdated`:

```
$ npm outdated
npm ERR! Not implemented yet

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jgallaso/.npm/_logs/2019-04-10T11_13_48_791Z-debug.log
```

The logs shows this error:

```
173 verbose stack Error: Not implemented yet
173 verbose stack     at Object.packument (/Users/jgallaso/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetchers/remote.js:12:22)
173 verbose stack     at Object.Fetcher#packument [as packument] (/Users/jgallaso/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/genfun/lib/genfun.js:15:38)
173 verbose stack     at packument (/Users/jgallaso/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetch.js:17:18)
173 verbose stack     at pinflight (/Users/jgallaso/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/packument.js:23:12)
173 verbose stack     at /Users/jgallaso/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/promise-inflight/inflight.js:29:24
173 verbose stack     at Promise._execute (/Users/jgallaso/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:313:9)
173 verbose stack     at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/Users/jgallaso/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:483:18)
173 verbose stack     at new Promise (/Users/jgallaso/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:79:10)
173 verbose stack     at _inflight (/Users/jgallaso/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/promise-inflight/inflight.js:28:25)
173 verbose stack     at /Users/jgallaso/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/promise-inflight/inflight.js:22:14
173 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (/Users/jgallaso/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
173 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/jgallaso/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
173 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/jgallaso/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
173 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/Users/jgallaso/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:606:10)
173 verbose stack     at _drainQueueStep (/Users/jgallaso/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:142:12)
173 verbose stack     at _drainQueue (/Users/jgallaso/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
```

When I run `npm outdated` on a specific package, for instance `eslint` I get the proper output:

```
$ npm outdated eslint
Package  Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
eslint    5.15.1  5.16.0  5.16.0
```

What's happening here? Is it due to some buggy package or a bug NPM itself?

Comment: [`npm update`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update.html) also encounters the same issue/bug as reported [here](https://npm.community/t/6-9-0-npm-up-not-implemented-yet/6187)

Comment: Try **npm install** locally, and if you do not see any errors, try **npm update**, You should find a relevant error locally

Answer (score 3):

As a temporal solution you can install the latest npm:

```
npm i npm -g
```

Answer (score 0):

`npm i` then `npm update` worked for me.